Why is $\sum_{i\ge n}{3^{2n-1}\over2^{2i-1}}{i-1\choose n-1}{i-1\choose j}$ an integer?
Given positive integers $0<j<n$, prove that
$$f(n,j)=\sum_{i\ge n}{3^{2n-1}\over2^{2i-1}}{i-1\choose n-1}{i-1\choose j}$$
is always an integer.
The motivation is that $\sum_{i\ge n}\sum_{0\le j<n}{1\over2^{2i-1}}{i-1\choose n-1}{i-1\choose j}=\operatorname{A369580}(n)/3^{2n-1}$ gives the probability of the first player winning the following game: “Two players take turns flipping a fair coin; the first to $n$ heads wins.” (See https://oeis.org/A369580.) The recurrence given in the OEIS entry should yield a proof, but I'm hoping for a more direct way of proving this, perhaps by manipulating the sum in a way that makes the fact obvious.
I've verified this numerically up to $n=15$, and the fact that OEIS A369580 is itself an integer sequence lends credence to the claim.

Can you tell us why you think it is an integer?

Seeking to show that with $0\lt j\lt n$ the following is an integer:
$$2 \times 3^{2n-1} \sum_{q\ge n} \frac{1}{2^{2q}}
{q-1\choose n-1} {q-1\choose j}
\\ = \frac{1}{2} \times 3^{2n-1} \sum_{q\ge n-1} \frac{1}{2^{2q}}
{q\choose n-1} {q\choose j}.$$
We can lower the sum starting value to $q=0$ because the first
binomial coefficient is zero in the added range when $n\ge 2$:
$$\frac{1}{2} \times 3^{2n-1}
[z^{n-1}] [w^j] \sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{1}{2^{2q}}
(1+z)^q (1+w)^q
\\ = \frac{1}{2} \times 3^{2n-1}
[z^{n-1}] [w^j] \frac{1}{1-(1+z)(1+w)/4}
\\ = 2 \times 3^{2n-1}
[z^{n-1}] [w^j] \frac{1}{3-z-(1+z)w}
\\ = 2 \times 3^{2n-1}
[z^{n-1}] \frac{1}{3-z} [w^j] \frac{1}{1-(1+z)w/(3-z)}
\\ = 2 \times 3^{2n-1}
[z^{n-1}] \frac{(1+z)^j}{(3-z)^{j+1}}
= 2 \times 3^n
[z^{n-1}] \frac{(1+3z)^j}{(3-3z)^{j+1}}
\\ = 2 \times 3^{n-1-j}
[z^{n-1}] \frac{(1+3z)^j}{(1-z)^{j+1}}.$$
This shows that we have an integer as the scalar in front is an integer
and we are extracting a coefficient from the product of two series, one
finite, with integer coefficients. Actually doing the extraction we
find the positive integer value
$$2 \times 3^{n-1-j}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {j\choose q} 3^q {n-1-q+j\choose j}.$$

Your expression can be simplified to
$$f(n,j)=2\cdot 3^{-j+n-1}\cdot \binom{j+n-1}{j}; _2F_1(-j,1-n;-j-n+1;-3)$$
$_2F_1(a,b;c;z)$ is the hypergeometric function.

This solution generalizes your problem, which is stated as a corollary at the end. While this generalization follows from the method of differences, I will present the details instead of just making the claim. If you don't want to wade through the details, see Notes 1 and 2 below for a "two idea" proof that is left as an exercise.
Definition: An integer-valued polynomial $f(n)$ is one that takes on integer values on the integers.
Generalization: Fix a positive integer $k\geq 2$.
Suppose $f(n) $ is an integer-valued,  degree (at most) $ d$ polynomial.
Let $S(f,k) =   \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{f(n)} { k^n }  $.
Then, $(k-1)^{d+1} \times S(f, k)$ is an integer.
Proof: Induction on $d$.
Base case: $d =0$, follows from $\sum \frac{ 1}{ k^n} = \frac{k}{k-1} $.
Let $g(n)$ be an integer-valued, degree $d+1$ polynomial.
Let $f(n) =  g(n+1) - g(n).$ Show that this is an integer-valued, degree (at most) $d$ polynomial.
Since we have an Polynomial-Geometric progression, apply the standard trick (of method of differences):
$$(k-1) S(g, k) = kS(g, k) - S(g, k)  = g(1) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ g(n+1) - g(n)}{k^n} = g(1) + S(f, k).$$
So $(k-1)^{d+2} S(g, k) = (k-1)^{d+1}g(1)  + (k-1)^{d+1} S(f, k)$ is an integer as desired.   $_\square$
Corollary: Fix integers $0 < j < n$. Consider $h(x) = {x -1 \choose n-1 } { x-1 \choose j }$, which is a degree $n-1 + j \leq 2n-2 $ polynomial with integer-values. Then,
$$\begin{align} 
f(n, j) & =  \sum_{i\ge n}{3^{2n-1}\over2^{2i-1}}{i-1\choose n-1}{i-1\choose j} \\
&  =  2 \times 3^{2n-1} \sum_{i\ge 1}{1 \over 4^{i}}{i-1\choose n-1}{i-1\choose j} \\
& = 2 \times 3^{n-1-j} \times [3^{n-1 + j + 1} S( h, 4)]. 
\end{align} $$
Hence $f(n, j)  $ is an integer as desired.
Furthermore, it is a multiple of $ 2\times 3^{n - 1 - j } $ (which Marko also showed).

Notes

An integer-valued polynomial can be written as an integer-linear combination of ${ n \choose i }$ for integers $ 0 \leq i \leq \deg(f)$.
Observe that (through method of differences, or calculus)  $$\sum \frac{n \choose i } { k^n } = \frac{1}{(k-1)^{i+1}}, $$  so the generalization follows by applying Note 1.
The generalization is easily guessed, esp if you're familiar with $$ \sum \frac{n^0}{k^n } = \frac{ 1}{ k-1}, \sum \frac{ n^1}{ k^n } = \frac{k}{(k-1)^2 } , \sum \frac{ n^2 } { k^n } = \frac{k(k+1) } { (k-1)^3}.$$

However, those alone are not sufficient for this problem, because we have a denominator to deal with. What we really need was the $ \sum { n \choose i  } / k^n$.



